# Select option of same table - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  product     option
1   55          78
2   55          55
3   55          42

4   68          78
5   68          62
6   68          36

7   94          25
8   94          47
9   94          81
```

How can I select all option where I have option 78 for example? I need to select 55, 42, 62, 36 because product have option 78.

Comment: option is a reserved word in MySQL, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct `option`
from your_table
where product in (select distinct product from your_table where `option` = 78)
```